# What is the replacement for the deprecated "with-query-results" function in clojure/java.jdbc 0.3.0?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I am migrating my code that currently uses clojure/java.jdbc 0.2.0 to the new 0.3.0 API.

There are a lot of newly deprecated functions in the 0.3.0 API.

I have been using "with-query-results" extensively but this is now deprecated, so what is the direct replacement function to use to get equivalent behaviour to this?

```
(defn get-user [username]
  (jdbc/with-connection db
    (jdbc/with-query-results results
      ["select username, password, roles from users where username = ?" username]
      (cond
        (empty? results)
          nil
        :else
          (first results)))))
```

I know that "with-connection" is no longer needed, but after that the available documentation is very unclear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processing resultsets can now be done within the scope of the top level java.jdbc functions through two new named parameters: `:row-fn` and `:result-set-fn`. The first transforms each row, the second the collection of rows. If the `:result-set-fn` returns a lazy sequence, you will get a connection or resultset closed exception when using it later. The default `:result-set-fn` is `doall`. When using your own, make sure it is realized.

```
(query db
       ["select firstname, lastname from users where username = ?" username]
       :row-fn #(str (% :firstname) \space (% :lastname))
       :resultset-fn first)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want something like:

```
(let [results (jdbc/query db ["select ..." ...] :as-arrays? true)]
  ...)
```

See [here](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html#reading-and-processing-rows) or [in the respective documentation](http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/query).