# How to iterate over a result set and extract one particular value in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Below is my attempt to iterate over a result set and get its values

```
(sql/with-connection db 
 (sql/with-query-results rs ["select * from user where UserID=?" 10000] 
    (doseq [rec rs
        s   rec]
  (println (val s))
)))
```

But how do you extract one particular value from it; i need only the user name field.

Can anyone please demonstarte how to do this?

Comment: Well, you could alter the query to only return the requested information: `"select name from user where UserID=?" 10000`

Comment: I want all the values to be displayed  as well. And  extract one particular field to perform other functions.

Comment: What SQL library are  you using?

Comment: @Thumbnail looks like clojure.java.jdbc - https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result set is a sequence of maps, so if you wanted to obtain one field (e.g. one called `name`) then:

```
(sql/with-connection db 
  (sql/with-query-results rs ["select * from user where UserID=?" 10000] 
    (doseq [rec rs]
      (let [name (:name rec)]
         (println "User name:" name)
         (println "Full record (including name):" rec)))))
```

But as mentioned in the comments, if you only want name, then `select name from` would be the more efficient option.  The code above is useful when you need the full row for something else.

Answer (score 2):

The `with-connection` / `with-query-results` syntax is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336652/what-is-the-replacement-for-the-deprecated-with-query-results-function-in-cloj/22598216#22598216) as of clojure.java.jdbc 3.0. Filtering results can be done much easier with the new `query` syntax and additional `:row-fn` and `:result-set-fn` parameters.

```
(query db ["select * from user"]
          :row-fn :name
          :result-set-fn #(doall (take 1000 (drop 10000 %))))
```

Be sure to make the result-set-fn realize all values, it shouldn't return a lazy sequence (hence the `doall` in this example).