# How to add a record to an existing map?

Tags: clojure

I have a map obtained from running a sql query.

```
(defn print-info
  [rs]
  (doseq [req rs]
    (let [rs1 req]
      (println "rs1" rs1))))

(defn display-info
  [uname]
  (sql/with-connection
     db 
     (sql/with-query-results rs
                             ["Select * from user"]
                             (print-info rs))))
```

Now i have copied the result set into another map. Is there any way to add another record to this existing map and return this new map to another function ?

Comment: You can assoc a record onto a map, is that what you're meaning?

Comment: with `query` there would be `:row-fn` where you could assoc to each row

Comment: I suggest adding "SQL" or "database" before "record" in the title and text, if that's what you mean, because "record" also has [another more common meaning](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord) in Clojure.  Also, it would help a

Comment: Ignore the partial sentence.  5-minute limit bit me.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the non-deprecated `query` syntax which was explained in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436217/how-to-iterate-over-a-result-set-and-extract-one-particular-value-in-clojure), you can use the `:row-fn` to manipulate each record in a resultset. A default row is a map, so if you use only functions that return a map (like in this case `select-keys`), you can just use `assoc` to add a new key-value pair to the map.

```
(query db ["select * from user"]
          :row-fn #(assoc (select-keys % [:name]) :type :user))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking when I want to make a fix to a record I'll use *merge*, which merges any number of maps in a left-to-right direction. Thus:

```
user=> (merge {:foo 1 :bar 2 :ban 3} {:bar 20} {:ban 300})
{:foo 1, :bar 20, :ban 300}
```

Although the *assoc* approach mentioned above also works, I find *merge* generally more useful and more flexible.

This applies to anything represented as a map, of course, not just records!

As an aside I'd strongly recommend using [Korma|http://sqlkorma.com/] for your database queries.